# Error running .NET CF 3.5 program in XP Embedded

Tags: .net-cf-3.5, windows-xp-embedded

I cannot run an application made for .net compact framework 3.5 in a POS with windows XP Embedded SP3, the error shown is "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application" so I checked over and over again and confirmed the .net compact framework 3.5 is installed and that the application uses this framework. How can I make the application run?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .net compact framework is for WinCE or Windows Embedded Compact.
Windows XP Embedded is a striped Version of Windows XP and you should use normal .net instead of .net compact. But I think you can run .net compact applications with full .net framework  as long as they only access the shared parts of both frameworks. So try installing full .net framework.

Comment: Actually, I must point out that the setup of .net framework was performed through windows update because the downloaded installer failed.